# Django 2 Sendmail with timeweb.ru

Tags: python, django

I checked Django app in Ubuntu 18.04 without ufw
When added to settings.py these:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.timeweb.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@timeweb.ru'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'myemail@timeweb.ru'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'myemail@timeweb.ru'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Run in the console

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>> send_mail('ddd','fffffffffff', 'myemail@timeweb.ru',['test@gmail.com'],fail_silently=False)
```

After 7 minutes I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/mikhail/Django/Chapter01/mysite/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 60, in send_mail
        return mail.send()
      File "/home/mikhail/Django/Chapter01/mysite/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 291, in send
        return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
      File "/home/mikhail/Django/Chapter01/mysite/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 103, in send_messages
        new_conn_created = self.open()
      File "/home/mikhail/Django/Chapter01/mysite/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 63, in open
        self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
        (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 338, in connect
        (code, msg) = self.getreply()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 394, in getreply
        raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
    smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure port 465 is the correct port for timeweb.ru? Look at the instructions of your mail host to check this. Normally this port is quite outdated and modern hosts use 587. Apart from that, nothing is wrong with your code, apparently your smtp host doesn't accept incoming connections over this port or from your origin.

Comment: This is data from an official site. With  GMAIL server works fine.

Comment: You should then contact support of your mail provider. It's not an issue of your code.

Comment: If you use port 587 or port 25, it displays another error

Comment: Can’t help. Contact support. It’s something on their side.